# Trying to get access token with the help of refresh token gives java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, google-api, access-token

So I am trying to get access token with the help of a refresh token with the method below,

```
public String refreshAccessToken() throws IOException {
        String refresh_token = "****";
        String client_id = "****";
        String client_secret = "****";
        GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(
                new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),
                refresh_token, 
                client_id,
                client_secret)
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Access Token:"+response.getAccessToken().toString());
        return response.getAccessToken().toString();
    }
```

Calling following method returns below exception
`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException cannot inherit from final class com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException`

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: This means that `com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException` is `final`. But [that class doesn't seem to be `final`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/main/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException.java#L29) at all. Looking at the blame, that line was changed 10 years ago. What exact version of  google-http-java-client do you use?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I use current version 1.41.8.